# je google, tu googles… : gougler ou gougueler?

Tags: conjugaison, anglicismes

On entend ici https://youtu.be/sQQr1V-Q-SQ?t=134 le verbe *googler* au conditionnel présent.  La forme sous-jacente du verbe semble être /gug*ə*le/ plutôt que /gugle/.  Que diriez-vous pour *je google*?

- je gougle /guglə/
- je gouguèle /gugɛl/
- je gougueule /gugœl/

Comment: Personnellement, je ne google plus depuis longtemps, maintenant je [qwante](https://www.qwant.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a effectivement plusieurs modèles en compétition pour la conjugaison du verbe dérivé de google, ce qui peut résulter en un verbe extrêmement irrégulier pour un emprunt si récent.

Le premier modèle est basé sur l'usage direct du nom google /gugœl/ comme verbe à l'indicatif présent (je google, prononcé /ʒ(ə)ɡuɡœl/). Sur base de cette forme, on tire un verbe régulier du 1er groupe, avec une racine uniforme (en gras ci-dessous) sur laquelle s'attache tout suffixe éventuel:

- Googler /**gugœl**e/
- Tu googles /ty**gugœl**/
- Tu googlais /ty**gugœl**ɛ/
- Tu  googleras /ty**gugœl**ra/
- Tu googlerais /ty**gugœl**rɛ/

Le deuxième modèle découle d'une réinterprétation du /œ/ de la racine précédente en schwa /ə/, qui disparait au milieu d'un mot dans la plupart des variétés du français. Comme la question le note bien, une telle racine devrait donner naissance à des formes avec un è ouvert à l'indicatif présent, au futur et au conditionnel, sur le modèle de verbes comme jeter ou lever. Je n'ai cependant jamais entendu une telle forme, /œ/ étant systématiquement préféré à /ɛ/ dans ces contextes :

- Googler /**gugl**e/
- Tu googles /ty**gugœl**/
- Tu googlais /ty**gugl**ɛ/
- Tu  googleras /ty**gugœl**ra/
- Tu googlerais /ty**gugœl**rɛ/

Le troisième modèle est basé sur la graphie où des formes comme googler ou googlerais dominent. Une telle graphie indique une racine en /gu:gl/ avec un schwa épenthetique à certaines formes :

- Googler /**gugl**e/
- Tu googles /ty**gu:gl**/
- Tu googlais /ty**gugl**ɛ/
- Tu  googleras /ty**gugl**əra/
- Tu googlerais /ty**gugl**ərɛ/

Pour ne pas faciliter les choses, les locuteurs ne sont pas consistants et peuvent utiliser plusieurs de ces modèles à la fois en variation libre, ou alors utiliser différents modèles pour différents temps.

Malheureusement, la graphie est ici trop trompeuse et l'emprunt trop récent pour que les ngrams soient utiles, et je n'ai connaissance d'aucune étude scientifique sur le sujet. Une enquête de type françaisdenosrégions questionnant les francophones sur leur usage serait probablement la meilleure méthode pour dégager des conclusions sur la popularité de chacun de ces modèles, mais je ne peux offrir qu'une description anecdotale du phénomène.

J'utilise personnellement le deuxième modèle, en 
alternance avec le troisième au futur et au conditionnel

Answer (score 2):

Comme on prononce habituellement google : **gougueule** /gugœl/
On utilise généralement cette forme lors de l'emploi du verbe : je **gougueule**, tu **gougueules**, ...

Il peut également arriver de le prononcer **gougler**, mais c'est plus rare. 'Tu n'as qu'à le **gougler**'

En revanche on ne le prononce jamais **gouguèle** /gugɛl/

Answer (score -2):

On trouve [ici](https://www.lalibre.be/economie/entreprises-startup/je-google-tu-googles-il-google-51b87d0ce4b0de6db9a85bfb) un article qui semble accepter comme acquis déjà en 2003 le terme pour le concept de recherche générale d'information au moyen d'un moteur de recherche. Le verbe est donc selon cette source belge « googler » (je google, tu googles, il google, etc.).

Comme on n'hésite pas introduire dans le langage le graphème « oo » (look, cool, pool, booléen, …) je ne vois pas pourquoi il faudrait le transcrire dans ce cas particulier, au contraire. Personnellement, je ne comprends pas la nécessité de ce graphème qui sera toujours prononcé /ou/ en français, du moins pour ce qui est d'une longue période de temps à venir ; il me semble qu'il est préférable de transcrire « oo » par « ou » (louk, koul, poul, bouléen).

Comment: Ma question porte plutôt sur la prononciation de "googler" aux différents temps, modes et personnes du verbe, pas tant sur la graphie dont tout le monde s'accorde, je crois, pour la laisser inchangée par rapport à l'anglais.  J'ai francisé l'orthographe pour mieux faire voir les diverses prononciations envisageables.